# Python: How to avoid the loops in building this matrix and to calculate the determinant of it faster?

Tags: python, loops, matrix, time, coding-efficiency

I have some problems when building a matrix in Python.
There is a loop in each element, [each element A_{ij}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPQna.png) is in the form as in the picture, here x is an array of q elements (which is denoted by xi in the following codes).

I have tried the codes as below, but it takes too much time. I think it is because of the number of loops, so I am thinking about see it as two matrices' product, but it didn't work since lambda has two dimensions.

Since these codes will appear as a function and will be used many times, is there any way to make it go faster? Thank you sooooo much!!

```
def lambdak(i,j,alpha,rho):
    return math.pi * alpha**2 * rho * math.exp(-math.pi**2 * alpha**2 *(i**2 + j**2))
def phik(i,j,x,alpha,rho):
    return cmath.exp(2 * math.pi * 1j * (i*x[0] + j*x[1]))
alpha = 0.5
rho = 50
num = 30
x = np.random.uniform(-0.5,0.5,num)
y = np.random.uniform(-0.5,0.5,num)
xi = np.zeros((num,3))
for i in range(num):
    xi[i] = np.array([x[i], y[i], 0])
q = len(xi)
A = [[np.sum(list(map(lambda j:
                     np.sum(list(map(lambda i:
                                    lambdak(i,j,alpha,rho)/(1-lambdak(i,j,alpha,rho))* phik(i,j,xi[x]-xi[y],alpha,rho),
                                    range(-N,N+1)))),
                     range(-N,N+1)))) for x in range(q)] for y in range(q)]
a = np.linalg.inv(A)
```

Comment: Just by looking at your code , I could give you a few suggestions. 1) You could  move computing lambdak(i,j,alpha,rho) in a separate function and store it in a 2D array. You don't have to recompute it for every q.   2) Also this code can be parallelized as in, you could compute each value independently but python has a GIL limitation. Basically it means,  even if you implement multi threading with python you wont see a significant speedup.But there are subtle optimizations like caching that  can definitely make your code an order faster.

Comment: @skippy thx so much for your answer! I'll try with the first point!

Comment: @skippy But for your second point, can you explain it a little bit further? I've looked into "caching" but since I'm not that familiar to it, I'm completely lost XO

Comment: No problem. So what I was trying to get with (2) was that maybe python might not be the right tool to parallelize your code , which basically has for-loops nested under it but every iteration isn't dependent on the previous or next one. You might want to look at say go-lang or c++ that provide you better concurrency models unlike python which has a GIL (https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Also ,your above code can be pushed to GPU for a definite increase in speedup. Torch is a Lua based script that can run on a GPU (http://torch.ch/) but GPU's might be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect, the reason for the bad performance is your loops. I assume you are using `numpy`, since you call `np.sum` in your loop. The trick is then to turn the loops inside out, and instead pass larger structures (i.e., matrices) to the `numpy` functions.

Doing this, can speed up performance dramatically. The code presented above, can be modified to:

```
import numpy as np

def lambdak(i,j,alpha,rho):
    return np.pi * alpha**2 * rho * np.exp(-math.pi**2 * alpha**2 *(i**2 + j**2))

def phik(i,j,x,alpha,rho):
    return np.exp(2 * np.pi * 1j * (i*x[:, :, 0] + j*x[:, :, 1]))

alpha = 0.5
rho = 50
num = 30
x = np.random.uniform(-0.5,0.5,num)
y = np.random.uniform(-0.5,0.5,num)
xi = np.zeros((num,3))
for i in range(num):
    xi[i] = np.array([x[i], y[i], 0])

X = np.arange(num).reshape(1,num)
Y = np.arange(num).reshape(num,1)

xi_diff = xi[X] - xi[Y]

N = 30

A = np.sum(map(lambda j:
                np.sum(map(lambda i:
                        lambdak(i,j,alpha,rho)/(1-lambdak(i,j,alpha,rho))* phik(i,j,xi_diff,alpha,rho),
                        range(-N,N+1)), 0),
                     range(-N,N+1)), 0)

a = np.linalg.inv(A)
```

Here the outer loops are converted to a matrix, which is passed as a whole to the `numpy` functions. In addition I pre-calculate xi_diff, since the whole structure is passed in each call (even if only a part is used by `phik()`).

This gives a dramatic speed-up. However, the numeric stability in the calculations may be affected, and when I compare the outputs from the two approaches they differ by about .1 percent. Hopefully this is OK, though.